# how to use POSTMAN app to upload FILES to Amazon S3

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, postman

I have a rather simple task.  I want to test uploading a file using **Postman** to my Amazon s3 bucket.  Postman keeps erroring out saying "Could not get any response".  Screenshot of my Postman configuration is below... any ideas why I can't do a simple upload to S3? (yes my signing credentials are correct)

[image]

Comment: Can you try importing the relevant cert in Postman - http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but just in case someone got stuck in the same issue.

In your screenshot the second reason for the issue might be the SSL and it is the issue. I don't know why; but AWS is providing S3 objects with self-signed SSL certificates and this is blocked by the chrome browser. If you copy the URL from postman to the browser it will be something like that.

[image]

following this blog post from postman [here](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/) will solve the issue depending on your OS.

Summing up the solution for windows (other platforms on the blog link):

1. Copy the URL into the chrome browser and proceed anyway.
2. Click on the lock icon at beside link and save the certificate.

[image]

3. Go to Chrome > Settings, search for SSL (chrome://settings/search#ssl) and click on Manage certificates.

[image]

4. Import the certificate and restart both chrome and postman

[image]

5. Use the link again in Postman and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this article: https://medium.com/@christinavhastenrath/testing-file-uploads-to-aws-s3-with-iam-user-credentials-in-postman-5026fbde3ca6

Note: `Add authorization data to` to `Request URL` in authoriztion.